# mvc3 DropDownFor not validating for nested property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

In a view I am adding an object of type person (for simplicity). However, the validation for a dropdown of which car of all cars to choose (for example) will not show up before a post. Let me elaborate.

In my controller I setup a viewmodel to pass in. The populating is not a problem. Here are the simple versions of the models.

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
 public Person Person { get; set;}

 public List<Car> Cars { get; set;}
}

public class Car
{
 [Key]
 public int CarId { get; set;}
 [Required]
 public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
 [Key]
 public int PersonId { get; set;}
 [Required]
 public int CarId { get; set;}
 [Required]
 public string FullName { get; set;}
}
```

Okay, pretty basic so far. In the view is the problem.

In the view:

```
@model PersonViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Add Person</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">Car</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.Person.CarId,
            new SelectList(
                Model.Cars,
                "CarId",
                "Name",
                0
            ),
            "-- Select A Car --"
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Person.CarId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.Person.FullName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.FullName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Person.FullName)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Person" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

When this view is rendered, a form to create a person is created. In the form, a dropdownfor list is generated with car names, and a person's name field is available. If a car is selected and a person's name is filled in, then create is clicked, the post goes through with no problems.

However, here is the discrepancy. If a person's name is not filled in and create is clicked then the input box is highlighted red with the message saying name is required. If a car is not chosen, then the form will submit. In the controller, this is easy to catch under `if(ModelState.isValid)`, but I would like to point out to the user that their person has no car. Adding the field `[Required] public int CarId` to the viewmodel and then referencing that through the binding will stop the form from being submitted if no car is chosen but seems to be a hacky solution.

The reason for the validation not being checked is that for some reason the generated `<select>` html object is lacking the added decoration `class="input-validation-error" data-val-required="The field is required." data-val-number="The field must be a number." data-val="true"`.

How can I make sure this decoration is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes` is somehow set to `false`. This means that the Required attribute won't be automatically added for value types such as integers. If you set it to true, the required attribute will be automatically added to the metadata of all value types and the HTML5 `data-*` attributes will be emitted. Its default value is `true` though.

To avoid this kind of problems you could use a real view model:

```
public class CreatePersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel Person { get; set;}
    public List<CarViewModel> Cars { get; set;}
}

public class CarViewModel
{
    public int CarId { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? CarId { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set;}
}
```

Notice that we no longer need a PersonId property for this view model since we are creating a new person which doesn't have an id assigned yet. Also notice that the CarId is declared as nullable integer and decorated with the Required attribute. Since in our dropdownlist we allow for a default value (`-- Select A Car --`) we must properly reflect that on the view model by using a nullable type.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution here, and your overall awesomeness on SO. Unfortunately your guess did not help, I still do not get the extra markup. What I had noted in the question, and as you state in your answer, is the current solution that is place where CarId is again explicitly defined in the viewmodel along with its annotations, data suggestions, filters, etc. etc. etc.. Unfortunate that it has to be this way because I am tired of copy pasting values from my data models to view models. Copy paste leads to errors. Also, having to manually setup fields in the view model...

Comment: ...means that I have to manually map them over to the entity before it is persisted dulling the nice aspects of using a special model for the view.